# Why INSERT sometimes insert empty record instead of filling them out?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table in a db where users add data constantly, now from this table I take some columns and do INSERT in a second db ('mysql2') :: connection, I use student_id to not allow it to have a dublicated record ne db2. But my problem is that sometimes INSERT puts empty data in db2, I do not know why this happens but in the table of db1 the data is filled in while in db2 sometimes the data passes "" (empty).

Use a cronjob to execute every minute as the data is updated every moment

```js
$data = DB::connection('mysql2')
    ->table('students')
    ->where('status', '=', 'Y')
    ->get();

foreach ($data as $key => $aStudent) {
    // Check if student_id duplicated
    $existing_data_in = DB::table('student')
        ->where("student_id", $aStudent->student_id)
        ->first();

    if (! $existing_data_in) {
        DB::connection('mysql')->table('student')->insert([
            "first_name"        =>$aStudent->first_name,
            "last_name"         =>$aStudent->last_name,
            "age"               =>$aStudent->age,
            "student_id"        =>$aStudent->student_id,
            "created_at"        =>$aStudent->created_at
        ]);
    }
}

Log::info('Success, Data Updated');
```

Or maybe should I run cronjob rarely? My problem is when some record on table1 are filed with data and when this record goes to table2 are empty on table2. If I check same student_id on table1 is okay but on table2 are saved empty

---

i have loged my query on cronjob and this is what i get in case i find an empty filed on table 2. So last name on table 1 in this case is filled with really last name but on table 2 is inserted as empty and this is query (what hapend)

```js
[2022-01-19 14:16:17] local.INFO: select `student_id` `first_name`, `last_name`, `age`, `created_at` from `students` where `student_id` = ? limit 1 [421] 

// this comes from query where i check for dublicated lines i think
[2022-01-19 14:16:17] local.INFO: select * from `student` where `student_id` = ? limit 1 [421] 

[2022-01-19 14:16:17] local.INFO: insert into `student` 
(`student_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `age`, `created_at`) values 
(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
["421","name","","38","2022-01-19 14:13:35"]
```

Iam using laravel 6.X version

Comment: I don't know what is your requirement but rather creating cron job for above requirement why you would not add same functionality after inserting user data on first table. Just need to replace DB connection which you already do in cron function.

Comment: If i check for studnet_id = '421' in table sondazhes i see last name filled

if i check for student_id = '421' in table sondazhe where i insert data with job every 1 minut, last_name is empty

this is poblem. How can help if i replace DB connection?

Answer (score -1):

To simplify your code, you can use updateOrCreate or firstOrNew, something like this:

```
DB::connection('mysql')->table('student')->updateOrCreate($aStudent);
```

OR

```
DB::connection('mysql')->table('student')->firstOrNew($aStudent);
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html

as I see that key value of array you are passing to create are same, you can simply pass $aStudent.

Comment: now i get this error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::updateOrCreate()   .I cant use $aStudent couse later i need to set a custom colum like  ```"first_name"        =>$aStudent->first_name,
            "last_name"         =>$aStudent->last_name,
            "age"               =>$aStudent->age,
            "student_id"        =>$aStudent->student_id,
            "created_at"        =>$aStudent->created_at, "custom"        =>$aStudent->88```

Comment: in your specific case it should be firstOrCreate and updateOrCreate. 
What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: `updateOrCreate` and `firstOrNew` are only for Eloquent, not Query Builder

Comment: I am using laravel 6. And for me work ```upateOrInsert```  But i dont know if this will fix my problm